# Registry Export Gives Hexadecimal Value

Tags: windows, batch-file, registry, regedit

During export of below command, all the values are in hexadecimal value, even though in Reg Editor it appears in as normal string.
Particularly `ProfileImagePath`

`REG Export "HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows NT\CurrentVersion\ProfileList`"

Reg Editor =

```
     `Name`         `Type`         `Data`
```

`ProfileImagePath` `REG_EXPAND_SZ` `C:\Users\ABC`

After Export it appears as = ( have changed the hexa values slightly )

```
"ProfileImagePath"=hex(2):43,00,3a,00,3a,5c,55,00,73,00,65,00,72,00,73,00,5c,\
  6b,65,00,72,00,61,00,6e,00,61,00,00,64,2e,00,64,00,65,00,65,61,70,00,61,00,\
  2b,00,00,2a
```

Requirement is, `Data` value of `ProfileImagePath` should be stored in a variable. In case there are multiple users(multiple SID), then store in same variable with line as seperator.

Comment: so you want to dehex the data?

Comment: Are you asking why the registry export has chosen to represent the data in that way?  It's difficult to tell without seeing the *actual* output, but at a guess because the string contains one or more characters that the registry export format doesn't permit.  (This doesn't necessarily represent a problem with the actual value in the registry.)

Comment: @npocmaka if dehexing is possible,... i thought it would show like `ProfileImagePath=C:\Users\ABC` I want the `C:\Users\ABC`

Comment: @HarryJohnston Oh, i just want to store that value and to be able to use it. My approach would have been to export and then cut all the `ProfileImagePath` and its value into a variable... but now its in hex.

Comment: `reg export` is for saving the data in a file, if you want it in a form you can process use `reg query` as per Trigger's answer.

Answer (score 0):

Uhh???????

```
C:\Users\User>reg query "HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows NT\CurrentVersion\ProfileList"

HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows NT\CurrentVersion\ProfileList
    ProfilesDirectory    REG_EXPAND_SZ    %SystemDrive%\Users
    Default    REG_EXPAND_SZ    %SystemDrive%\Users\Default
    Public    REG_EXPAND_SZ    %SystemDrive%\Users\Public
    ProgramData    REG_EXPAND_SZ    %SystemDrive%\ProgramData

HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows NT\CurrentVersion\ProfileList\S-1-
5-18
HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows NT\CurrentVersion\ProfileList\S-1-
5-19
HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows NT\CurrentVersion\ProfileList\S-1-
5-20
HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows NT\CurrentVersion\ProfileList\S-1-
5-21-2820837959-2753176274-143444667-1000
HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows NT\CurrentVersion\ProfileList\S-1-
5-21-2820837959-2753176274-143444667-1006
HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows NT\CurrentVersion\ProfileList\S-1-
5-21-2820837959-2753176274-143444667-1009
HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows NT\CurrentVersion\ProfileList\S-1-
5-21-2820837959-2753176274-143444667-500
```

or

```
for /f "tokens=7 delims=\" %A in ('reg query "HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows NT\CurrentVersion\ProfileList"') do echo %A
```

Comment: Also, if you know which value you want, you can use the `/v` option.  That may save you some parsing.  Although really for this sort of thing you're probably better off working in Powershell or vbscript rather than batch, which isn't actually designed for programming per se.

Comment: True. The reason for this is that Win 95 (just maybe WfW 3.11)didn't support Reg_Expand_SZ.

Comment: I think Windows NT 3 was the first one with a registry.  WfW still used .ini files if I remember correctly. :-)

Comment: No COM created the WfW3.11 registry. It was very, very, small. About a 14 programs' file association, basically wordpad, paint, faxviewer, and office's com file registration.

Comment: PS it was 14, I started WfW3.11 in a VM and counted. I just thought you may have installed other programs, so the `about`. Then I realised you don't use it so have installed nothing,